# MySQL Query with MySQLParameters in C#

Tags: c#, mysql

I am currently developing an Application for Windows using MySQL and C#. I have the following code:

```
    private void cboCategories_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
            {
                DatabaseWork dbase = new DatabaseWork();
                try
                {
                    dbase.openConnection();
                    string query = "SELECT * FROM budgetcategory WHERE budc_userID=@userID AND budc_category=@category";
                    MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand("", dbase.conn);

                    cmd.CommandText = query;
                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@userID", userID);
                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@category", cboCategories.SelectedItem.ToString());

                    MySqlDataReader reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();
                    while (reader.Read())
                    {
                        setCatId(reader.GetString("budc_category_id"));
                        Console.WriteLine("Category ID: " + getCatId());
                    }
                }
                catch (MySqlException ex)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("Cat Error: " + ex.Message);
                }
                finally
                {
                    dbase.closeConnection();
                }
}
```

For some reason when I debug the code it never goes into the while loop as if nothing was ever returned from the database. But I know there should be something in there.

Thanks for any help you can provide

Answer (score 0):

Just trying to help you debug a little:

Try reducing these three lines:

```
string query = "SELECT * FROM budgetcategory WHERE budc_userID=@userID AND budc_category=@category";
MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand("", dbase.conn);
cmd.CommandText = query;
```

to just:

```
string query = "SELECT * FROM budgetcategory WHERE budc_userID=@userID AND budc_category=@category";
MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand(query, dbase.conn);
```

Now put a breakpoint on those lines that add the parameters, and make sure that `userID` and especially `cboCategories.SelectedItem.ToString()` have the values that you expect.

Also, can you confirm that no exception is thrown?

If this is not the case run the query, with those exact values directly against the database and confirm that something is returned.

Comment: Hi, thanks for your suggestions. cboCategories does come back with the correct value, and no exception is thrown. The weird thing is even if I hardcode the values of the parameters it still never goes into the while loop. Also if I don't use parameters and put the variables directly into the query string it works fine. Its only the MySQL Parameters that aren't working